# How do I get temp values to be set after an insert has occured in a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trigger I am working on that will insert rows into a table when another table has inserts or updates applied to it. So far the Update portion works (the column that I'm most concerned with is the Balance column), but when the first row is added for an insert on the Account table, in my AuditTrailCustomerBalance table OldBalance, NewBalance and CustNo are set to NULL. How can I get NewBalance and CustNo to reference to the values that were just inserted into the table from the trigger?

Here is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER AuditTrigger
ON Accounts
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS      
IF UPDATE( Balance )
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 'True'
        FROM Inserted i
        JOIN Deleted d
        ON i.AccountID = d.AccountID
    )
    BEGIN           
        --1. Declare temp variables.
        DECLARE @OldBalance NUMERIC( 18, 0 )
        DECLARE @NewBalance NUMERIC( 18, 0 )
        DECLARE @CustNo INT

        --2. Set the variables.
        SELECT @OldBalance = Balance FROM deleted
        SELECT @NewBalance = Balance FROM inserted
        SELECT @CustNo     = CustNo FROM inserted

        INSERT INTO AuditTrailCustomerBalance( TimeChanged, ChangedBy, OldBalance, NewBalance, CustNo )
        VALUES( GETDATE(), SUSER_SNAME(), @OldBalance, @NewBalance, @CustNo )   
    END
END
GO
```

And the test statement:

```
INSERT INTO Custs( CustNo, GivenName, Surname, DOB, SIN )
VALUES( 1, 'Peter', 'Griffen', 'January 15, 1950', '555555555')

INSERT INTO Accounts( CustNo, Type, Balance, AccruedInt, WithdrawalCount )
VALUES( 1, 'Savings', 0, 0, 0 )

UPDATE Accounts SET Balance = 100 
WHERE CustNo = 1
```

Comment: Your trigger is broken. You need to write *set* based queries that access `inserted` and `deleted` because those tables can contain *multiple* rows (or no rows), so assignments to scalar variables will select arbitrary values (not even all necessarily from the same row). And in a single `UPDATE` statement, *some* rows may have had their balances changed and others may not.

Comment: Okay, I am still new to using triggers so instead of SELECT for the assignment of the variables, I should be using SET is what you're saying?

Comment: No, I'm saying that `SELECT @NewBalance = Balance FROM inserted` is fundamentally flawed because `inserted` might contain 3 rows - with 3 different balance values - but obviously `@NewBalance` can only be set equal to *one* of those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you want something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER AuditTrigger
ON Accounts
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS  
    INSERT INTO AuditTrailCustomerBalance(TimeChanged, ChangedBy,
                                          OldBalance, NewBalance, CustNo )
    SELECT GETDATE(), SUSER_SNAME(),
           COALESCE(d.Balance,0), i.Balance, i.CustNo
    FROM inserted i
            left join
         deleted d
            on
               i.AccountNo = d.AccountNo
    WHERE
        i.Balance <> d.Balance OR
        d.Balance IS NULL
```

As I said in my comments, `inserted` and `deleted` can contain [*multiple* rows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) (or no rows) and so you need to take that into account and write a set-based query that deals with all of those rows - also *some* rows may have had balance changes and some not - so deciding whether to write any entries based on `UPDATE(Balance)` was also flawed.

Answer (score 0):

you can if you are sure of your code write something like this :

if (select count(*) from inserted) = 1

and execute your code.

You can for the insert do like this :

insert into AuditTrailCustomerBalance (.....)
select .... from inserted

as already posted, the problem with your trigger is in the calling if you update one row or multiple (same for insert)